# Random Output from Ability Score Function C

Tags: c

The code that I'm writing looks fine and provides no compilation errors or segmentation faults, but it provides completely random numbers in the output file.

```
int reroll()
{
    return rand() % 5 + 2; // range of 2-6
}

int roll()
{
int i;
int rolls[4];
int sum = 0, low = 6;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    rolls[i] = rand() % 6 + 1; // range of 1-6
    while(rolls[i] == 1)
    {
        rolls[i] = reroll();
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (low > rolls[i])
        low = rolls[i];
}

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    sum += rolls[i];
}

sum = sum - low;

return sum;
}

void abScores()
{
int i, j, choice, abSc[6], abil[6];
char abS[6][5] = {"Str", "Dex", "Con", "Int", "Wis", "Cha"};
FILE *fp;
FILE *fo;
fp = fopen("csheet.txt", "a");
fo = fopen("att.txt", "r");

printf("Would you like your own ability scores, or the basic ability scores?\n");
printf("1 for own, 2 for basic\n");
scanf("%d", &choice);

if (choice == 1)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        abSc[i] = roll();
        printf("Ability score %d: %d\n", i+1, abSc[i]);
    }
}
else if (choice == 2)
{
    abSc[0] = 15;
    abSc[1] = 14;
    abSc[2] = 13;
    abSc[3] = 12;
    abSc[4] = 10;
    abSc[5] = 8;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        printf("Ability score %d: %d\n", i+1, abSc[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    printf("What score would you like for %s?\nPlease use each score only once.\n", abS[i]);
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        printf("%2d\n", abSc[j]);
    }
    scanf("%d", &abil[j]);
    system("cls");
}

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    fprintf(fp, "%s: %d\n", abS[i], abil[i]);
}
```

I'm trying to make a rather basic D&D Character Generator, but this function, abScores, is causing me more problems than the other 11 functions combined.

Comment: What is a _D&D Character Generator_?

Comment: Dungeons and Dragons Character Creator. The race choice, class choice, and background choice functions work fine, but the abScores function is the one that causes me problems.

Comment: one printf("%2d\n", abSc[j]); what does this 2 doing there. two these are functions and when you scanf some values to arrays they might now remain after function is over. you should pass them by parameters as reference to the function if you want to keep them after. 
also to avoid any seg fault, when you initialise arrays such as abSc[6], abil[6]; assign default values to them so they can be lets say printable in compilers eye. 
also dont forget to close your files after you are done with them. in case someone else opens them in the meanwhile. good luck

Comment: Please use a debugger to examine your code. If you can reduce the code the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exercise might help you find the problem.

Comment: Where is `main()`?

Comment: Main is only used to run the function. There isn't much used for the function as is in the question.

Comment: Please read this: [mcve].

Comment: Well in the lack of complete code I had to made up my own wrapper, and all I can say, is the prompts, input requirements and output are baffling. Please work out your own logic, this is off topic.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &abil[j]);` is the same as `scanf("%d", &abil[6]);`, outside  array bounds.  Did you want `scanf("%d", &abil[i]);`?

Comment: "Main is only used to run the function. There isn't much used for the function as is in the question" may be true from your point-of-view, yet a complete compile-able code snippet would aid those trying to help and engender's better responses to help you. (a win-win).